# How to draw only axis in R for 3d plot?

Tags: r, 3d, plot

Basically I only want to draw the x, y, z axis with empty plot, but with x, y, z of my own labels on it. Is it possible to do it in R? I know how to draw it in 2d plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(0,0,0, pch="", xlab="X", ylab="Y",zlab="Z", 
              xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), zlim=c(0,1))
```

The position of Y label seems a bit strange. This is a limitation of this package. So you may set `ylab=""` and then manually put the label to your desired place by `text(x, y, "Y")`

[image]

Comment: but I noticed it's not showing  from 0 for each axis, and the pisition of Y axis label is a little strange.

Comment: Thank you! But I noticed the Y axis label is a little strange, do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe it's your turn to solve the problem and edit the answer!